# Как проверить существование элемента в объекте данных

Tags: python, telegram

Работаю с Core Telegram API. Получаю список участников чата, информация по участнику выводится в таком виде

```
{
    "_": "pyrogram:ChatMember",
    "user": {
        "_": "pyrogram:User",
        "id": 456488888,
        "is_self": false,
        "is_contact": false,
        "is_mutual_contact": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "user"
    },
    "status": "member"
}
```

или такой пример

```
{
    "_": "pyrogram:ChatMember",
    "user": {
        "_": "pyrogram:User",
        "id": 483362460,
        "is_self": false,
        "is_contact": false,
        "is_mutual_contact": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "\u0412\u0438\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f",
        "last_name": "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430",
        "photo": {
            "_": "pyrogram:ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgADqacxG6ytzxwACCsSMw4ABDYsn7Nwvs8xgJsAAgI",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgADqacxG6ytzxwACCsSMw4ABHg-J0efOQjJgpsAAgI"
        }
    },
    "status": "member"
}
```

Хочу получить данные какого то одного элемента, допустим мне нужны все фамилии пользователей, но данного элемента может и не быть, как мне пропускать или заменять отсутствующий элемент, к примеру прочерком.

Я вывожу так

`data.user.last_name` и вот этого `last_name` может и не быть, скрипт выдает ошибку, какую проверку сделать?
Может я не совсем понятно описал свой вопрос, не так давно начал изучать Python.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets я получаю весь список пользователей, он состоит из множества объектов, в том виде который я привел в примере, потом я пропускаю их через цикл FOR что бы выбирать элементы по одному, и этот элемент записывается в переменную data. И уже работаю с data в том же цикле, далее я прописываю путь к нужным мне данным data.user.last_name, но так как фамилия не обязательные данные у телеграм, пользователь может это поле и не заполнять, и тогда в элементе не будет вообще этой записи, но так как я пытаюсь вызывать этот элемент у всех пользователей, то возникает ошибка.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets как в PHP работать с таким я знаю, а вот в Python нет. Хотелось по проще получать эти данные, сразу обращаясь к элементу объектов, но этого элемента может и не быть вообще, мне это не очень нравится в выводе данных телеграм, могли бы просто выдавать пустое поле или False.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdef#dict.setdefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет понять такой пример:

```
d = [
     {"a":1, "b":2},
     {"a":1, "b":7},
     {"a":1},
     ]

for el in d:
    print(el.setdefault("b","_"))
print(d)
```

На выходе будет:

```
2
7
'_'
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 7}, {'a': 1, 'b': '_'}]
```

То есть во время поиска вам надо обращаться к словарю не `d['b']`, а `d.setdefault("b","_")`. Но будьте внимательны - тогда исходный словарь меняется ))

Comment: Да, я уже разобрался. Спасибо.